# Text-align property does not work inside button

Tags: html, css, button, svg, text-align

I am developing interactive map. I have svg vector map itself and different buttons(divs with link inside), styled as circles. Vector, buttons and pop-ups are nested in div "map". The click on button link opens the pop-up with text. The problem is: I cannot center-align the link text on a button.Text is centered, but sticks at the top of the button. I have tried to nest link inside button with same styling as my "div variant" has now - that is the only way i get normal centered link texts. But such way is invalid - doesnt work for IE and moz

```css
.button-my{width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFC651 !important ;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFC651 !important;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;;
    font-size: 20%;
    top: 34%;
    left: 49%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;}
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
0% {opacity: 1}
50% {opacity: 0.5}
100% {opacity: 1} 
    }



.button-my:hover {
  transform: scale(4);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 5;
-webkit-animation: none;
}


.my{
    display: inline-block;
    top: 33%;
    left: 45%;
    background-color: #00C3D1;

    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0,5%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width:10%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    transition: opacity 800ms;
    z-index: 5;
    }
.my:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: auto;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div{
    z-index: 5;
}

.map{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="map"><img src="../img/graph.svg">
       
    <div class="button-my"><a href="#my">Text</a></button>
      
       <div class="my" id="my"><a href=" 
     
    http://www.my.com" target="_blank"><h1>Random pop-up text</h1>
        </a>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        
      </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either increase the `line-height` to 25px so it fills the height of the button, or increase the top padding to push the text down into position.

You should almost always avoid using `height` in CSS. In this case, it's better to change the height of the contents to achieve the height you want... then the height of the button will be determined from that (line-height + top padding + bottom padding).

Answer (score 0):

```
.button-my {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It may be you con elaborate more on your answer, what was originally done wrong? - so it helps someone else, who would hit this topic from search

Comment: The height of text-wrapper is 25px, but the text is smaller, so it produces a lot of empty space under text. Putting `line-heigth = height` aligns text center by vertical.

Answer (score 0):

add line height to a

```
   .button-my a{
          line-height: 25px;
    }
```

```css
.button-my{width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFC651 !important ;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFC651 !important;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;;
    font-size: 20%;
    top: 34%;
    left: 49%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;}
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
0% {opacity: 1}
50% {opacity: 0.5}
100% {opacity: 1} 
    }



.button-my:hover {
  transform: scale(4);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 5;
-webkit-animation: none;
}

.button-my a{
      line-height: 25px;
}


.my{
    display: inline-block;
    top: 33%;
    left: 45%;
    background-color: #00C3D1;

    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0,5%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width:10%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    transition: opacity 800ms;
    z-index: 5;
    }
.my:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: auto;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div{
    z-index: 5;
}

.map{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="map"><img src="../img/graph.svg">
       
    <div class="button-my"><a href="#my">Text</a></button>
      
       <div class="my" id="my"><a href=" 
     
    http://www.my.com" target="_blank"><h1>Random pop-up text</h1>
        </a>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        
      </div></div>
```